# Why ls and stat shows different modified dates?

Tags: stat

When I ls a file the last modified date shows as Nov 29 11:13, am but stat shows the file changed at Dec 3rd, why is the date different on ls and stat output.

```
-rw-rr 1 iadm sys     266240 Nov 29 11:13 log_backup_1_0_26337600_26341632.1417281197106
-rw-rr 1  iadm sys    1585152 Nov 29 11:13 log_backup_0_0_0_0.1417281197131


stat log_backup_0_0_0_0.1417281197131
  File: `log_backup_0_0_0_0.1417281197131'
  Size: 1585152         Blocks: 3096       IO Block: 32768  regular file
Device: 22h/34d Inode: 17232       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1002/  iadm)   Gid: (   79/  sys)
Access: 2014-11-29 11:13:17.000000000 -0600
Modify: 2014-11-29 11:13:17.000000000 -0600
**Change: 2014-12-03 09:56:57.618281823 -0600**
 Birth: -


stat log_backup_1_0_26337600_26341632.1417281197106
  File: `log_backup_1_0_26337600_26341632.1417281197106'
  Size: 266240          Blocks: 520        IO Block: 32768  regular file
Device: 22h/34d Inode: 17231       Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1002/  iadm)   Gid: (   79/  sys)
Access: 2014-11-29 11:13:17.000000000 -0600
Modify: 2014-11-29 11:13:17.000000000 -0600
**Change: 2014-12-03 09:56:57.606281658 -0600**
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l` shows only the time of last modification of the content of the file, and `stat` additionally gives you time of last change of the file in the file system structure (inode modification).

For example lets compare time stamp before and after a change of the file name:

```
$ touch abc.txt
$ stat abc.txt

(...)
Access: 2014-12-05 19:23:18.515079101 +0000
Modify: 2014-12-05 19:23:18.515079101 +0000
Change: 2014-12-05 19:23:18.515079101 +0000

$ mv abc.def def.txt
$ stat def.txt

(...)
Access: 2014-12-05 19:23:18.515079101 +0000
Modify: 2014-12-05 19:23:18.515079101 +0000
Change: 2014-12-05 19:24:45.306744159 +0000
```

Notice the same "Modify" time, but time of last "Change" has changed.

If you want to see "Change" time with `ls` use `-lc` option, from `man ls`:

> -c with  -lt: sort by, and show, ctime (time of last modification of file status information) with -l: show ctime and sort by name otherwise: sort  by  ctime, newest first

So:

```
$ ls -l def.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jimmij jimmij 0 Dec  5 19:23 def.txt
$ ls -lc def.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 jimmij jimmij 0 Dec  5 19:24 def.txt
```

Comment: thx much jimmij